# How can I create a launcher in 11.10?

Tags: 11.10, launcher

After I upgraded to 11.10, the Create New Launcher option has disappeared from the menu (Right click anywhere on desktop).

It also doesn't look like the "Finder" can find anything named "launcher"

So how can I create a launcher on the desktop in 11.10?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I create launchers on my desktop?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/64222/how-can-i-create-launchers-on-my-desktop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can find your application in the dash, just click and drag the icon onto your desktop

Or if you want to do it manually,

[Look at this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64222/how-can-i-create-launchers-on-my-desktop)

Answer (score 0):

All launchers are .desktop files. [Freedesktop Specs](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/index.html) Although if you are wanting to create a unity launcher there are a few extra features you could add. [examples](http://maketecheasier.com/8-really-useful-ubuntu-unity-quicklists/2011/05/07)